# Hugo .Data.Pages in partial only works on root (index.html) but not on other pages

Tags: hugo

I have a `nav.html` partial with this in it:

```
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                {{ range $.Data.Pages }}
                {{ if ( not ( .IsPage) )}}
                <a class="dropdown-item" href={{ .Permalink }}>{{ .Name }}</a>
                {{ end }}
                {{ end }}
            </div>
```

It works on the root of my site, but does not work when rendering a page or list "inside" the site.

How do I access the "root" context `.Data.Pages` no matter where I am in the site so my nav partial works all the time?

Answer (score 1):

I found it, `.Data.Pages` is for the current node, I wanted this:

```
              {{ range $.Site.Pages }}
               {{ if ( eq .Kind "section" )}}
                <a class="dropdown-item" href={{ .Permalink }}>{{ .Name }}</a>
               {{ end }}
              {{ end }}
```

https://gohugo.io/variables/page/